# AutoFac Registration of Propery Injection works for AuthorizeAttribute but not ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, containers, autofac

I have some custom MVC attributes

I am using autofac to configure the properties and inject them

I have the following code

```
 builder.RegisterType<LogWrapper>().As<ILogger>().SingleInstance();
 builder.RegisterFilterProvider();


  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
  public class MyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {    
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
    Logger.Log("Test");
    }
  } 

  public class MyAttribute2 : AuthorizeAttribute
  {
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
    Logger.Log("Test 2");
        return true;
    }
   }
```

The property is Injected for MyAttribute2 and not my attribute

Answer (score 1):

The reason was MyAttribute was setup as a global filter in the global.asax

so it needed the following code

```
 builder.Register(c => new MyAttribute())
                  .PropertiesAutowired()
                  .AsActionFilterFor<Controller>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```